# Moved some properties inside an object, and related event is not triggered anymore

Tags: vue.js

EDIT: The issue was due to another data that was not mentioned in the question. I don't want to delete this but also don't want to keep it open. If you are a moderator, please close this question.

Originally `stageStat` looked like:

```js
  data() {
    return {
     stageStat: {
       total: 0,
       success: 0,
       fail: 0,
     };
   }
  }
```

I moved some properties inside `testCount` to make it look cleaner (`stageStat` has many properties-which I removed in this example for clarity- and this felt like a good idea). Let me add the querying part based on graphQL & Apollo, but I have checked that values were properly stored in `stageStat` so it shouldn't be the issue.

```js
  data() {
    return {
     stageStat: { 
       testCount: {
         total: 0,
         success: 0,
         fail: 0,
       },
     };
   }
  }

  ...

  query stageStat($id: ID!) {
    stageStat(id: $id) {...}
  },
    result(res) {
      this.isLoadingStats = false;
      if (!res.data || !res.data.stageStat) {
        this.stageStat = {
          testCount: {
            total: 0,
            success: 0,
            failed: 0,
          },
        };
        return;
      }
      this.stageStat = res.data.stageStat; // will have testCount object
      // 2:HERE
    },
  },
```

I changed the part that use `stageStat` to be compatible with this change

```html
<div v-if="stageStat.testCount && stageStat.testCount.total"> // 1:HERE
      <div
        class="success"
        @mouseover="setToolTip($event, 'success')"
        @mouseout="hideToolTip($event)"></div>
      <div
        class="failed"
        @mouseover="setToolTip($event, `failed`)"
        @mouseout="hideToolTip($event)"></div>
</div>
```

**issue**
I found that `mouseover` and `mouseout` event is not linked to the `div` element. I have tried changing `v-if` to `v-show` but with no effect. I don't see an error message as well.

**info1**
Another thing to add in case it suggests something is that if I change the part I highlighted with `1:HERE` to

```
<div v-if="stageStat.testCount.total">
```

it keeps complaining that `vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1888 TypeError: Cannot read property 'total' of undefined`, as if `stageStat.testCount` was not initialized.

**info2**
I have also tried explicitly setting the values on the line I marked with `2:HERE` but it didn't also work.

```
        this.$set(this.stageStat.testCount, 'success', res.data.stageStat.success);
        this.$set(this.stageStat.testCount, 'cancelled', res.data.stageStat.cancelled);
```

Does anyone notice something?

Comment: Did you debug res.data.stageStat ? It's not guaranteed that it has testCount, while this is assumed. It's unknown how you integrated gql to Vue but make sure that `this` is component instance.

Comment: As you gave advice, I double checked on the values and found that I didn't make another object `X` (not mentioned in this question) that is calculated value of `stageStat.testCount` reactive by using `this.$set`. Object `X` gives width to the `div` where the event was linked so that was why I couldn't see the event occurring. Thanks!